# Should a tab selection persist after refresh?

Tags: user-expectation, tabs, refresh

We're currently using MUI tabs.

If a user selects `ITEM TWO` in this example, is the expectation to persist this tab after the user refreshes the page? Or should it default back to `ITEM ONE`?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, persist the tab.** If a user is refreshing the page, most of the time it means something went wrong and they got stuck. It's a good practice to help them get back to what they were trying to do as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with izquierdo. While the refresh might not be a problem as such - the user might've been pulled away and the web app logged out, the user might be refreshing data, etc. - for many users, especially frequent SaaS users, the tab they're on at a given moment is likely to be their most-used tab. So let the place they last left themselves at persist. It's only one click to go to a different tab.